# How to fix Failed to start DevTools: Dart DevTools?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, devtools

I updateی dart sdk and flutter sdk to latest version and it happened to me. However, I replace the perviuos version of dart sdk, the error is shown to me.

[image: I updateی dart sdk and flutter sdk to latest version and it happened to me. However, I replace the perviuos version of dart sdk, the error is shown to me.]

Comment: might want to also raise an issue ticket. closest thing I could find from googling `github vscode issues "Failed to start DevTools" "code 1"` was https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3549. nvm. I see your https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4826